# tex2Dproj equivalent in Metal iOS

Tags: ios, metal

How do you do hardware accelerated texture projection in Metal? I cannot find any reference or resource that describes how to do it.

Comment: Do you have evidence that it was hardware-accelerated in OpenGL ES? I can't find anything on it. I don't think that the authors of Metal would have left this out if it actually mapped to hardware.

Comment: Now that you ask, I cannot find any reference of the ES hardware having accelerated projective texture mapping.

Comment: Although I would still love to know how to implement `tex2Dproj` in a Metal shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do the divide yourself.

OpenGL:

```
a = tex2Dproj( texture, texcoord.xyzw )
b = tex2Dproj( texture, texcoord.xyz )
```

Metal equivilent:

```
a = texture.sample( sampler, texcoord.xy/texcoord.w )
b = texture.sample( sampler, texcoord.xy/texcoord.z )
```

(Choose 'a' or 'b' depending on the type of projection you are doing, more commonly it is 'a')

Comment: I thought there was some more magic trick to that function, but apparently it's just a simple perspective divide :)